# How to understand this Observable recipe?

Tags: rxjs6

I have this methods which sends `http.post` message and returns an `Observable`. But I am a bit confused about how the program flow works.

Question 1 - Am I correct that in the following code, the `Observable` which is returned is the one from `finalize` and not the one from `http.post`?

`http.post` returns an `Observable`. The `pipe` takes that `Observable` and creates a composition of operators (`tap`, `catchError` and `finalize`, each taking `Observable` from previous operator and returning a new `Observable`. The `Observable` returned in the end is the one from `finalize`.

```
sendMessage(url:string, body:any,httpOptions){
        this.loaderService.show();
        let observable:Observable<HttpEvent<any>> = this.http.post(url,body,{
          headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
          withCredentials: true,
          observe: 'events', //what post should observe (look for). Here it means events. This could be body as well
          responseType: 'json' //responseType tells post how to interpret the body
        })
        return observable.pipe(tap((httpEvent:HttpEvent<any>) => {//tap transparently perform actions or side-effects, such as logging.
            if(httpEvent.type === HttpEventType.Response)
            {
              console.log('response from backend service:', httpEvent);
            }
            else {
              console.log("not an http response")
            }
              return httpEvent;

          })
          ,catchError(this.handleError)//error handler if Observable fails
          ,finalize(()=> this.loaderService.hide()));
      }
```

Question 2 - If I subscribe to the `Observable` returned by `sendMessage` (above) then the error handler will not receive error notification because `catchError` has handled it. It I want the application to receive error then `handleError` function should explicitly throw an error

```
sendMessage(...).subscribe(
next,
err, //this will not error notification unless catchError handler throws error
complete
)

private handleError (error: HttpErrorResponse) {

    let result:ServerResponseAPI = {result:"error", "additional-info":error.message,['http-status']:error.status.toString(),['http-status-text']:error.statusText};
    return throwError(result); //catch by error handler mentioned in the subscribe method

  }
```